# Array from variable is sent like a string in Postman

Tags: arrays, environment-variables, postman

I collected data from the response and pushed it into array in 'Tests'. `console.log` shows that I received array:

[image]

Then I saved it into environment variable to use in the next call. But value in the request was a string, so only the first value was running.

[image]

How can I set normal array?

Response from I collected data:

```
{
  "sent": 0,
  "remaining": 1000000,
  "gifts": [
    {
        "id": 43468,
        "amount": 50000,
        "can_gift_back": true
    },
    {
        "id": 43469,
        "amount": 50000,
        "can_gift_back": true
    }
  ]
}
```

My code in the "Tests" tab:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let gifts = jsonData.gifts;

//calculate array length
function objectLength(obj) {
    var result = 0;
        for(var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            result++;
            }    
        }
    return result;
}
let arrayLength = objectLength(gifts);

//push response data to the array
var giftsArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var giftsIDs = gifts[i].id;
        giftsArray.push(giftsIDs);
    }
pm.environment.set("giftsToCollect", giftsArray);
```

**UPD:**

1. After using code from the answer in different ways I received such issue.

**Point 1** from the picture describes the way of behavior when `stringify` is used

**Point 2** describes behavior when `stringify` is not used[image]
2. Example of request JSON with manually inputed ids [image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `JSON.stringify(giftsArray)` when saving it to the environment variable?

Comment: @DannyDainton, yes, I tried it in different variants, but it didn't help.

Comment: What does the saved variable look like, could you update with an image of that? Have you tried removing the quotes and brackets around the variable name in your request body? If it's saved in the environment as an array, all the would need is the `{{var_name}}` syntax.

Comment: Saved variable is *[5578,5579,5580]*. And in the request it is sent that way: `gift_ids=[5578,5579,5580,5581,5582,5583,5584,5585,5586,5587]` (it's captured request body from Fiddler) instead of every value at different level like at the screen from the my answer. Actually, your code didn't help me... and thanks for a short way to collect IDs :)

Comment: The code didn't help you? :)

Comment: Unfortunately. The 1 way to solve this issue is to send values from variable like manually inputted. But I can check it only in Fiddler, because visual sameness of saved variable and `gift_ids` in the 2d test doesn't mean the same acting. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyDainton the issue is with the variable calling. If input ids manually and enclose all ids with double quotes - the result will be the same: in the request all ids will be put in one string.

Comment: You might need to update or edit your question with the extra information / things that you have tried. Would be good to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You could capture all the `id` values in an array using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach), which is an external module that you can use in the Postman application.

Saving the `array` as a variable after this, is the same as you have done so already but I've added `JSON.stringify()` around the array value or it will save this as a string.

```
let giftsArray = []

_.each(pm.response.json().gifts, (item) => {
    giftsArray.push(item.id)
})

pm.environment.set('giftsToCollect', JSON.stringify(giftsArray))
```

You should then be able to reference the environment variable like this:

`gift_ids: {{giftsToCollect}}`

I've mocked out the request data locally, just to show you this capturing the values from the data.

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

The working hack is to add `pm.sendRequest` with the data **from the second test** to the "Tests" tab of the 1st test. In this case the 2d test does not run on the whole, but gifts are collected. It is not the best decision, but it works.

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();

let giftsArray = [];

_.each(pm.response.json().gifts, (item) => {
    giftsArray.push(item.id);
});

pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'http://url/api/gifts/collect',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Host': 'url',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify({'api_token': '48696295110ba1e8f9937820dc9b6626', 'user_id': '100650741100901', 'gift_ids': giftsArray, 'version': '6.0.0'})
    }
}, function (err, res) {
console.log(res);
});
```